# Why bean class should be serialized

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, javabeans

Why should bean classes be serialized?

I have seen bean classes in posts about spring MVC and they are always declared serialized and have a `private static final long serialVersionUID`. Why?

Comment: I have edited your post for grammar, but as I could not completely understand it, please check that the intent of the post as I have edited it is still the same as your original intent.

Comment: Your premise is simply false, so the question is unanswerable.

Comment: Thanks Hexafraction for correction

Comment: Beans don't have to be necessarily `Serializable`. You're mixing the JavaBeans convention with Spring beans. Spring beans are just objects that are managed by the container.

Comment: @Magnamag i am asking only javabeans refrence not Spring beans

Comment: @Saurabh.jd OK, understood. Sorry, I got confused because you mentioned Spring MVC in your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One good reason, with respect to servlets, is that if you put serializable beans into your web server session, your web server can serialize them to disk if it's shutting down, and then deserialize them back into memory when it starts up. In this way, users wouldn't lose their sessions / logins when the server comes back up.

If there are any non-serializable beans in session, tomcat will fail to serialize sessions to disk.

I believe it's also necessary if you want to sync sessions between multiple servers in a cluster.

Answer (score 3):

According [JavaBean specification](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/7224-javabeans-1.01-fr-spec-oth-JSpec/) beans should be  serialized. Actually any Java class can be a bean if it has the following properties:

1. Has a no argument constructor
2. Has some private members and to access/manipulate them has some getter/setter
3. Implements `serializable`

See the [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaBeans) definition of bean. So by definition they are serializable.

And the `serialVersionUID` is used as a universal version identifier for a `Serializable` class. After a class being serialized when deserialization process comes then this number is used to ensure that a loaded class corresponds exactly to a that serialized object.

Comment: Wasn't the question *why* are beans serialized? This answer just states the obvious: beans are serialized. Doesn't give a reason as to why

Comment: But Why Bean Should be Serialized

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.